# Open specific tutorial from learn panel from custom CEP Panel in Photoshop

Tags: adobe, photoshop, complex-event-processing, bridge

I have to open a specific tutorial from a CEP Panel in Photoshop.
I saw that in CSInterfece.js I have the requestOpenExtension function, through that I managed to open my own custom CEP Extensions but I do not know how to open the learn panel (where do i get the id from? ) and also how to start or at least point at a specific tutorial?

Thanks!